# ARkit - go inside house (3D walkthru)

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, virtual-reality, realitykit

I'm trying to use ARkit to create a simple demo where I would need to scan an image and display a 3D model of the house at the exact location defined by the image. This means that the picture would be the starting point 0 for me, and from this point I would show the house to which I could go in augmented reality. Is there any way to do this?

I came up with the method using image tracking, but I can't fix the position of the scanned image, the model always disappears when the mobile phone does not see the image.

My question is.
Is it possible to fix the position of the object after scanning the image, even if the phone will no longer point at it and can I walk 20 meters further?

Thanks for any help, I'm new to ARkit features.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue.

I recommend you use the method of cloning an object to the same location with 'Instantiate' after image tracking.
Or, I think it would be okay to utilize AnchorContent(position, prefab) by Anchor Manager.
[Anchor Content Method](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.1/manual/anchor-manager.html)
Then, Even if you don't see the image, the model won't disappear

My model doesn't disappear after image tracking, but when I walk 20 meters more,
The problem is that the position of the object changes slightly.

After solving your current problem, I would appreciate it if you could let me know if the position of the object is fixed well.